# Can we give any upper bound on $E[\max_{n \leq N} X_n]$ in terms of $\max_{n \leq N} E[X_n]$

Tags: pr.probability, martingales

Consider a sequence $\{X_n\}$ of $N$ random variables. Can we give any upper bound on $E[\max_{n \leq N} X_n]$ in terms of $\max_{n \leq N} E[X_n]$. I think in general it is not possible.

If $\{X_n\}$ is a zero mean martingale can we say something.

Comment: Indeed impossible in general: suppose you have a (continuous, increasing) function $f$ such that $\mathbb E[\max_n X_n] \leq f(\max_n \mathbb E[X_n])$. Consider the random sequence $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{N}$: pick $Y \in [1,N]$, set $X_Y = f(0) + 1$ and $X_i = 0$ for any other $i$. We have
$$\mathbb E[\max_n X_n] = \mathbb E[X_Y] = f(0) + 1,$$
and on the other hand,
$$f(\max_n \mathbb E[X_n]) = f(\mathbb E[X_n]) = f\left(\frac{f(0) + 1}{N}\right) \rightarrow_{N\rightarrow \infty} f(0),$$
Contradiction. This doesn't answer the question for a zero mean martingale.

Comment: Another counterexample: take $(X_n)$ iid of mean $0$, then $\max E[X_n] = 0$. But $E[\max X_n]$ can take pretty much any value; if the support of the distribution of $X$ is not bounded above, then as $N \to \infty$ it also goes to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can't get an upper bound, not even for martingales of bounded support.

Doob's $L^{p}$ inequality gives that if $(Y_{n})$ is a martingale, then $E\max_{m\leq n} |Y_{m}|^{p} \leq  q E(|Y_{n}|^{p})$ for $p>1$ and $q$ such that $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$, where $|\cdot|$ denotes absolute value.

However, this last conclusion is $\textit{not}$ true if $p=1$.  To see this, let $(S_{n})$ be the SRW (simple random walk) with $S_{0}= 1$. (That is, $S_{n}$ is the sum of $n$ independent random variables that take values $\{-1, 1\}$ with probability 1/2). Considering the stopped process $X_{n} = S_{\min\{n,K\}}$ for $K= \inf\{n: S_{n} = 0\}$, we have that $E(\max_{m\leq n} X_{m}) \rightarrow +\infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. (To check this remember that the probability that a SRW started at the origin hits $b$ before $-a$ is $\frac{a}{a+b}$ to calculate the tail of the distribution of the $\max X_{n}$ and show that their sum corresponds to the harmonic series, so that $E(\max X_{n}) = \infty$, and the claim follows by the monotone convergence theorem). However, $\max E(X_{n})=1$, as we have that $E(X_{n}) = ES_{0} = 1$, for all $n$ (this is a property of stopped martingales, see for instance Williams (1991), Probability with Martingales, section 10.9). Hope this helps.

Comment: It appears to me that there's something not clear in the counterexample given above my reply, as the same effectively reasoning can be used to lead to wrong conclusions. For this, take into account that Doob's inequality is true for non-negative submartingales, as for instance the square of the martingale (X_{n}) Vincent uses and assuming it has finite second moment. We then have $\max E(X_{n}^{2}) < \infty$, however $E(max X_{n}^{2})$ also tends to infinity by the same reasoning. Am I missing something?
ps. Sorry for the late reply comments are restricted by regulations of the site.